# Issue when importing Sp-PNP-JS

Tags: angular, design-patterns, sharepoint, typescript

Reg. unable to import sp-pnp-js

I am getting error when importing: import * as spns from "sp-pnp-js";

The error is Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token <  ... SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
        at eval ()
        at Object.eval ...

In js file i can see this happens when var spns = require("sp-pnp-js");

I have already installed sp-pnp-js

I have uploaded all the ts/js and node_modules in the stylelibrary of SharePoint
ts compile is fine but at run time i get this error

Comment: where used `var spns = require("sp-pnp-js");`

Comment: this is a generated code from ts to js